# Arduino sketch won't run until I open up GUI in processing

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, processing-lang

I am trying to make a human detection robot using D6T omron thermal sensor. However, I am facing some problem here. My Arduino Uno didn't run the sketches until I open up my GUI in processing. The tx/rx pin did not light up when I remove my USB serial cable from my PC and put in an external power supply to my arduino uno board. The tx/rx pin will only light up when I open my GUI in processing and everything works just fine.

I am trying to move my robot away from my PC. Therefore, it is a must for me to provide my board an external power supply but it just does not work. I am confused here. Fyi, it will be interfacing with my PC thru Xbee in the near future.

Ps: this is my final year project. Your effort will be much appreciated and credits will goes to you. Thanks guys!

Attached below is my code (Arduino sketch):

```
#define E_right 10
#define E_left 11

int RightMotorForward = 9; // Pin 10 has Left Motor connected on Arduino boards.
int RightMotorReverse = 8; // Pin 9 has Left Motor connected on Arduino boards.

int LeftMotorForward = 12; // Pin 12 has Right Motor connected on Arduino boards.
int LeftMotorReverse = 13; // Pin 13 has Right Motor connected on Arduino boards.

float top_sum, bottom_sum, left_sum, right_sum, center_row_sum;

#include <Wire.h>
#include <WireExt.h>

#define D6T_addr 0x0A
#define D6T_cmd 0x4C

int rbuf[35];
float tdata[16];
float t_PTAT;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.flush();
  pinMode(E_right, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(E_left, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LeftMotorForward, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
  pinMode(RightMotorForward, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
  pinMode(LeftMotorReverse, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
  pinMode(RightMotorReverse, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

// The following Loop is to make the Robot move towards heat source.
void loop()
{
int i;

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {     
    int inByte = Serial.read();     
    if (inByte == 0x0001) {         

      Wire.beginTransmission(D6T_addr);
      Wire.write(D6T_cmd);
      Wire.endTransmission();

      if (WireExt.beginReception(D6T_addr) >= 0) {
        i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
          rbuf[i] = WireExt.get_byte();
        }
        WireExt.endReception();

        t_PTAT = (rbuf[0]+(rbuf[1]<<8))*0.1;
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
          tdata[i]=(rbuf[(i*2+2)]+(rbuf[(i*2+3)]<<8))*0.1;
        }

      }
    }
  }


top_sum= tdata[0] + tdata[1] + tdata[2] + tdata[3];
bottom_sum= tdata[12] + tdata[13] + tdata[14] + tdata[15];
right_sum= tdata[0]+ tdata[4] + tdata[8] + tdata[12];
left_sum= tdata[3] + tdata[7] + tdata[11] + tdata[15];
center_row_sum= tdata[1] + tdata[2] + tdata[5] + tdata[6] + tdata[9] + tdata[10] + tdata[13] + tdata[14];



if ((left_sum>center_sum)&& (center_sum>right_sum))
{
   analogWrite(E_right, 230); 
   analogWrite(E_left, 205); 

   digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);   // turn the Right Motor ON
   digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);   // turn the Left Motor OFF
                  // wait for  0.5 seconds
   delay(500);
   //turn left
}

else if ((right_sum>center_sum)&&(center_sum>left_sum))
{
   analogWrite(E_right, 230); 
   analogWrite(E_left, 205); 

   digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);   // turn the Right Motor OFF
   digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);   // turn the Left Motor ON
   // wait for  0.5 seconds
   delay(500);
   //turn right
}
else if ((center_row_sum>right_sum)&&(center_row_sum>left_sum))
{

   analogWrite(E_right, 230); 
   analogWrite(E_left, 205); 

   digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);   // turn the Right Motor ON
   digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);   // turn the Left Motor ON
   delay(500); //forward

}

}
```

Attached below is my code in processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;

float[] tdata = new float[17]; 
float tptat; // PTAT
String portName; 
//int serialport = 0; 

String buf; 
float colourGreen; //change green in relation to temperature 

int lbTemp = 25; //lowest relative temperature
int hbTemp = 35; //highest relative temperature 
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class

void setup() {
  size(640,640);
  //println(Serial.list());
  //portName = Serial.list()[serialport];
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM7", 9600);
  myPort.clear();

}
void draw() {
  myPort.write(0x01); 
  delay(100); 
  while (myPort.available() > 0) { 
    delay(300); 
    buf = myPort.readString(); 
    myPort.clear();  
    tdata = float(split(buf, ','));  
    for (int i = 0; i <16; i++) { 
      colourGreen = map(tdata[i],lbTemp,hbTemp,255,0);
fill (255,colourGreen,0);

      if (i == 0)
    { rect(480,0,160,160);}
      else if (i == 1)
    { rect(320,0,160,160);}
      else if (i == 2)
    { rect(160,0,160,160);}
      else if (i == 3)
    { rect(0,0,160,160);}
      else if (i == 4)
    { rect(480,160,160,160);}
      else if (i == 5)
    { rect(320,160,160,160);}
      else if (i == 6)
    { rect(160,160,160,160);}
      else if (i == 7)
    { rect(0,160,160,160);}
      else if (i == 8)
    { rect(480,320,160,160);}
      else if (i == 9)
    { rect(320,320,160,160);}
      else if (i == 10)
    { rect(160,320,160,160);}
      else if (i == 11)
    { rect(0,320,160,160);}
      else if (i == 12)
    { rect(480,480,160,160);}
      else if (i == 13)
    { rect(320,480,160,160);}
      else if (i == 14)
    { rect(160,480,160,160);}
      else
    { rect(0,480,160,160); }

    if (tdata[i]<5) {fill(255);} else {fill(0);}
      if (i ==0)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]),560, 80);}
      else if (i == 1)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]),400, 80);
      }
      else if (i == 2)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 240, 80);
      }
      else if (i == 3)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]),80, 80); 
      }
      else if (i == 4)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 560, 240); 
      }
      else if (i == 5)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 400, 240);  
      }
      else if (i == 6)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 240, 240);  
      }
      else if (i == 7)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 80, 240); 
      }
      else if (i == 8)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 560, 400);
      }
      else if (i == 9)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 400, 400);  
      }
      else if (i == 10)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 240, 400);
      }
      else if (i == 11)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 80, 400);
      }
      else if (i == 12)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 560, 560);  
      }
      else if (i == 13)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 400, 560); 
      }
      else if (i == 14)
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 240, 560);
      }
      else
      {
      textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
      textSize(20);
      text(str(tdata[i]), 80, 560);  
      }
    }
    delay(800);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Arduino Uno didn't run the sketches until I open up my GUI in processing.

How do you know?

> The tx/rx pin did not light up when I remove my USB serial cable from my PC and put in an external power supply to my arduino uno board.

That is because the TX/RX LEDs are linked to the USB interface chip. With no USB connection there can be no lights.

> The tx/rx pin will only light up when I open my GUI in processing and everything works just fine.

That is because there is USB communication.

Your sketch is running fine. However your sketch looks to be wrong.  Major portions of it (i.e., the portion that does any detection at all) relies on serial data coming in.  How can you have it working, in that case, if you disconnect the serial interface so that no data ever comes in?

Comment: OHHHH! I see. Thank you so much for pointing out the mistakes. Do you hv any suggestion on how to improve my sketch? Sorry because I am new to these. Thanks a lot Majenko!

Comment: You don't appear to actually be doing anything with serial in your sketch. Just delete all references to it.

Comment: Okayyy! I will try it out and update you later. Thanks again Majenko! =D

Comment: It works! Thanks for pointing out my silly mistakes! Credits goes to you, Majenko~ Thanks!!